# rdkit.Chem.rdmolfiles.MolToMolFile(NoneType, str)

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, rdkit

I am trying to convert smi to sdf format using rdkit python library. I am running following line of python code.

```
def convertir_smi_sdf(file_smi):
    leer = [i for i in open(file_smi)]
    print(f"Total de smi: {len(leer)}")

    cont = 0
    cont_tot = []
    for i in leer:
        nom_mol = i.split()[1]
        smi_mol = i.split()[0]
        mol_smi = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smi_mol)
        Chem.MolToMolFile(mol_smi, f'{nom_mol}.sdf')
        cont += 1
        cont_tot.append(cont)
    print(f"Se ha convertido {cont_tot[-1]} smiles a SDF")
```

Any help is highly appreciated

I need this to separate this smiles format in distints sdf archives.

**Error:**

[image: Error]

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Comment: This error simply means that `mol_smi` is `None` which means `smi_mol` is not a valid SMILES string. Add a print statement to print `smi_mol` to manually verify what value are you getting there.

Comment: @betelgeuse I do it and I get a the entire list of SMILES

Comment: That's a bug then. Input to `Chem.MolFromSmiles` should be a SMILES string not list

Comment: @betelgeuse In the description I put a link for a picture of what I got

Comment: What's the last SMILES string after which error occurs? Is it `C(=O)([C@@H](N)CSSC[C@@H](C(=O)O)N)O`? Add a `print(smi_mol)` statement right before `Chem.MolToMolFile`

Comment: Again, in the the description i put a link. IKt run about 345 SMILES aprox

Comment: As I already mentioned, add a `print(smi_mol)` statement before `Chem.MolToMolFile` not after. The idea is to find out which SMILES is causing the error. If you add it after then how will you know since the code will never reach this line.

Comment: Sorry, I still confuse the words before and after.  The last one is Cl[Pt](Cl)([NH4])[NH4], as you can see

Comment: I added a proper answer below

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Comment: Since this got a score of -1 here, I'd just like to let you know that [MMSE has an rdkit tag](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rdkit) and your question would probably be better received there. You can ask future questions there if you want, and if you want this question migrated you can ping me by typing @NikeDattani and I'll flag it for migration.

Answer (score 1):

These kinds of errors always mean one thing: The SMILES you're inputting is invalid. In your case, you're getting the error because of the SMILES string `Cl[Pt](Cl)([NH4])[NH4]` which is invalid. See its picture below. Both Nitrogen atoms are forming 5 bonds without any positive charge on them.

[image: Error]

When you parse it in RdKit, you'll get a warning like this:

[image: rdkit warning]

To deal with this, either fix this SMILES manually or ignore it completely. To ignore it, just pass the argument `sanitize=False` as below:

```
mol_smi = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smi_mol, sanitize=False)
```

Just a warning: by adding `sanitize=False`, you'll be ignoring all the invalid SMILES.

Comment: How reliable is it to perform these types of actions?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what do you mean by reliable?

Comment: I mean reliable. I managed to solve the problem, I really appreciate your help.